# I have a blank Unity object nested under the player. It's supposed to be tied to the front of the sprite but does not flip with the sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got my player sprite that has a blank "Front Check" object nested underneath it. The nested item is used to check if the front of the sprite is touching a wall. the problem I'm having is the Front Check object does not flip with the sprite when I move in the opposite direction. it was working fine earlier today and then out of the blue just quit. This is my first unity project and I'm just not quite sure what's missing. Any help is much appreciated. here is an image of the project and my movement script.
[image]

```
    using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private BoxCollider2D coll;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;
    private Animator anim;

    [SerializeField] private LayerMask jumpableGround;

    public float checkRadius;
    bool isTouchingFront;
    public Transform frontCheck;
    public float wallSlidingSpeed;
    bool wallSliding;
    bool wallJumping;
    public float xWallForce;
    public float yWallForce;
    public float wallJumpTime;

    private float dirX = 0f;
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 7f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 14f;
    [SerializeField] private float airControl;

    private enum MovementState { idle, running, jumping, falling }

    [SerializeField] private AudioSource JumpSoundEffect;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        coll = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (dirX < 0 && IsGrounded())
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed * -1, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        else if (dirX > 0 && IsGrounded())
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        else if (dirX == 0 && IsGrounded())
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb.velocity.y);
        }
  


        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {
            JumpSoundEffect.Play();
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);

        }



        UpdateAnimationState();
    }

    private void UpdateAnimationState()
    {
        MovementState state;

        if (dirX > 0f && IsGrounded())
        {
            state = MovementState.running;
        }
        else if (dirX < 0f && IsGrounded())
        {
            state = MovementState.running;
        }
        else
        {
            state = MovementState.idle;
        }

        if (rb.velocity.y > .1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.jumping;
        }
        else if (rb.velocity.y < -.1f)
        {
            state = MovementState.falling;
        }

        //Wall Jump
        isTouchingFront = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(frontCheck.position, checkRadius, jumpableGround);

        if (isTouchingFront == true && IsGrounded() == false && dirX != 0)
        {
            wallSliding = true;
        }
        else
        {
            wallSliding = false;
        }

        if (wallSliding)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, Mathf.Clamp(rb.velocity.y, -wallSlidingSpeed, float.MaxValue));
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && wallSliding == true)
        {
            wallJumping = true;
            Invoke("SetWallJumpingToFalse", wallJumpTime);
        }

        if (wallJumping == true)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(xWallForce * -Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), yWallForce);
        }



        anim.SetInteger("state", (int)state);

    }

    void SetWallJumpingToFalse()
    {
        wallJumping = false;
    }

    public bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.BoxCast(coll.bounds.center, coll.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, .1f, jumpableGround);

    }
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (dirX > 0f)
        {
            sprite.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (dirX < 0f)
        {
            sprite.flipX = true;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Why should it? You are only using `sprite.flipX` which inverts the rendering of the sprite, not the actual direction of the object ...

Comment: alternatively you could try and do `var scale = transform.localScale; scale.x = Math.Sign(dirX); transform.localScale = scale;` which would actually change the scale accordingly. Note: I explicitly used `Math` and not `Mathf` because in the Unity `Mathf.Sign` it returns `0` if `dirX == 0` while in `System.Math.Sign` it still returns `1` for `dirX == 0` ;)

Comment: @derHugo Dude, that totally worked. I did end up using Mathf though as using Just the Math function caused my collisions with the ground to stop working. Thanks, this is also my first venture with C#, but I'm slowly starting to piece it together.

Comment: Haha yeah I just read up again and it is actually exactly the other way round of what I said ^^ `Math.Sign` returns `0` for `0` while Unity's `Mathf.Sign` returns `1` in that case ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sprite.flipX` only flips the rendering not the actual object scaling.

You rather want to use e.g.

```
var scale = transform.localScale;
scale.x = Mathf.Sign(dirX);
transform.localScale = scale;
```

Note that it needs to be `UnityEngine.Mathf.Sign` and **not** `System.Math.Sign` since the latter returns `0` for parameter `0` which would totally break your colliders etc. while `Mathf.Sign` returns only `-1` or `1`.